# MS Word Macros Difference between ^p and ^13

Tags: macros

I am using `search` and `replace` functions in Word Macros. But I could not figure out the basic difference between `^13` and `^p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are regular expressions.
use the `^p` character code to search for paragraph marks.
In MS Word, the `^13` character matches the paragraph mark at the end of each line.
So, no difference